# Is there a way to get system-wide Grammarly correction on MacOS?

Tags: macos, spellcheck

Is it possible to get Grammarly checking system-wide on MacOS? As far as I know, Grammarly only works as a browser plugin or Microsoft Office plugin (maybe more). Grammarly is fantastic, but the need to copy and paste my work into a designated Grammarly field is beyond inconvenient. Even a menu bar icon with a checker would be more convenient. I mainly work with 3rd-Party apps on Mac that don't have a Grammarly plugin.

I like how on iPhone Grammarly is a keyboard extension that captures your spelling live as you type.

What are some alternatives if this is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no such support with Grammarly for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Grammarly says it works across many apps on macOS without needing to copy and paste.

- https://www.grammarly.com/desktop

> An all-in-one writing assistant that works on your desktop and in your browser. Use it in apps, word processors, email clients, and more.

Have you tried the desktop application yet?